# iOS - Performing multiple AFJSONRequestOperations that write to Core Data in background

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, afnetworking, nsoperationqueue

I am having trouble determining the best way to manage updates to my apps SQLite database (using Core Data)

When my app launches, it hits a server to determine which tables need updating. I then do a service call for each of those tables. Once I get the JSON back for each, it creates/updates the corresponding objects in my SQLite DB.

What I am doing works, as it performs each request and updates each table that needs to be-- but I don't think I am doing this correctly.

Doing this still locks my UI Thread and I need to be able to run this code asynchronously in the background every 10 minutes or so.

```
AFJSONRequestOperation* operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {


        NSMutableArray *operations = [NSMutableArray new];

        //for each of the tables that need updating, create a AFJSONRequestOperation
        for(NSString *str in [JSON valueForKey:@"Views"])
        {

            NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cache/%@/?deviceUID=%@&token=%@", str, @"00000-00000-0000-00001", [_globals getToken]];
            NSURLRequest* request = [client requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:nil];
            AFJSONRequestOperation* operation2 = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) 
            {
                   [self updateTable:str withJSON:JSON];
            } 
            failure:nil];

            [operations addObject:operation2];
        }

        //AFHTTPClient
        [client enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:operations progressBlock:nil completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
            //this gets called way before the objects are done updating to the DB
            NSLog(@"DONE ALL REQUESTS");
            [_HUD hide:YES]; // getting called after getting all of the JSON not after all tables are updated
        }];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {

        [_HUD hide:YES];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failed" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }];


    [operation start];
```

Heres my updateTable function with only 1 condition

```
- (void)updateTable:(NSString *)tblName withJSON:(id)JSON
{
    for(NSDictionary *record in [JSON valueForKey:@"Records"])
            {
                NSString *viewName = [[record valueForKey:@"ViewName"] lowercaseString];

                //Worker
                if([viewName isEqualToString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Worker_vw_iSales"] lowercaseString]])
                {
                    if([Worker doesWorkerExist:[record valueForKey:@"JSONData"]])
                    {
                        NSLog(@"deleting old worker");
                        [ad.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[Worker doesWorkerExist:[record valueForKey:@"JSONData"]]];

                    }

                    NSEntityDescription *desc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([Worker class]) inManagedObjectContext:ad.managedObjectContext];
                    Worker *worker = [[Worker alloc] initWithEntity:desc insertIntoManagedObjectContext:ad.managedObjectContext];
                    [worker initWithJSONSting:[record valueForKey:@"JSONData"]];
                    NSLog(@"Creating Worker: %@", worker.firstName);


                }
    }
}
```

I hope this is not all too confusing-- if so I can try to explain more.

I may be doing this completely wrong, and if I am just let me know. I have tried a few other things, including using an NSOperationQueue instead of AFHHTTPs `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:requests` but I cannot get the behavior I am looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: From what you described, it sounds like the operation success blocks are being started, but the `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:operations` is starting at an unrelated time. I haven't used `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:operations` before, but I know it isn't waiting for your batched operations to finish. My best guess is that the batch success block runs once all the operations have returned and I believe I read somewhere that if you want to do what you are trying to accomplish is that you just need to run all your updateDataTable calls in that block.

Comment: THanks-- I ended up fixing my issues with the MBProgressHUD, but my main problem now is that I need this to run in the background so it does not lock the UI. I just updated my question a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for now is `setSuccessCallbackQueue:` on AFJSONRequestOperation. AFNetworking set all their success blocks to run on the main queue unless otherwise specified.

What I've done is

```
@implementation myClass {
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue;
}

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]){
        backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.proj.myClass", 0);
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)doSomeStuff
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[myAFAPIClient sharedClient] requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:params];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *myOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
    //Success Block
    }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) { 
    }];
[myOperation setSuccessCallbackQueue:backgroundQueue];
[[myAFAPIClient sharedClient].operationQueue addOperation:myOperation];
}
```

So the different would be you are enqueue'ing operations, where I'm just adding them straight to the client.

Also, where I have //Success Block I do all sorts of things such as dispatching other methods onto backgroundQueue, which those methods make more JSON requests and I don't have any issues.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and my UI is still locking up-- I cannot switch tabs or my UISegmentedController until everything is finished. Hmm-- I have to be doing something dumb

Comment: Two things I would try. 1st: do `NSThread *mainThread = [NSThread mainThread];
    if([mainThread isMainThread]){
        NSLog(@"Why am I on main thread");
    }`
inside the success block of the operations.
2nd: If you are indeed on background threads, a really crude thing to do would be to make your operation success blocks do nothing and ensure that your batch success block isn't hanging up your main thread.

Comment: So it seems I am in the main thread-- I placed the MainThread line you just gave me right before my `[self updateTable:str withJSON:JSON];` call

Comment: Could it be because I am creating these requests within the success block of a request that is on the MainThread?

Comment: I updated my answer with some more code. You should have no issues with where you are creating the operations. I do that sort of thing all the time. You could try doing what I've done (just adding it to the client) and see if it lands on the background thread. Actually while typing this it makes me wonder if the `enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations` somehow makes everything land on the main thread?

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot! I am now able to switch tabs, and I still get my updating logs. I still cannot switch my UISegmentedControls though, but I know that has to do with the fact that my tabs access my  Core Data objects and display them in a table (so im sure there are sync issues going ont).. but that is probably another whole question itself